# Pass a value from selected option inside for loop from view to controller .NET 6

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a view where I send list of employee And shifts in view model ,
I use for loop depending on how many dates in it and inside it select list for employee and shifts
when I submit the form the model comes without the selected items only the first Selection

here is my controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSheduleWithEmp(int DepartmentId, DateTime Start, DateTime End)
             {
                 List<string> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + End.Subtract(Start).Days)
               .Select(i => Start.AddDays(i).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
               .ToList();
                 // .ToArray();
                 //ViewBag.Dates = dates;
                  
                 if (DepartmentId != 0)
                 {
                     var Shifts = await eRDbContext.Shifts.ToListAsync();
                     var model = await eRDbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == DepartmentId).ToListAsync();
                     EmpShifts EmpShiftsView = new EmpShifts
                     {
                         DepartmentID = DepartmentId,
                         Employees= model,
                         Shifts = Shifts,
                         Dates = dates
                            
                     };
                     return View("AddEmployeeToShifts", EmpShiftsView);
        
                 }
               return View();
             }
```

the view

```
  <form asp-action="SaveShifts" class="form" method="post">
        
                                 @if (Model.Dates != null)
                                 {
                                     <table class="table table-striped">
                                         <thead>
                                             <tr>
        
                                                 <th>Date</th>
                                                 <th>Emplyoee</th>
                                                 <th>Shift</th>
                                                 <th>Priorety</th>
        
                                             </tr>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>
                                             @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Dates.Count; i++)
                                             {
        
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td>
                                                         @Model.Dates[i]
                                                     </td>
                                                     <td>
                                                         <select class="form-select" asp-for="EmployeeID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Employees,"Id","Name"))">
                                                             <option>Please Select Employee</option>
                                                         </select>
                                                     </td>
                                                     <td>
                                                         <select class="form-select" asp-for="ShiftsID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Shifts,"Id","Name"))">
                                                           
                                                         </select>
                                                     </td>
                                                     <td>
                                                         <select>
                                                             <option value="1st Oncall">1st Oncall</option>
                                                             <option value="2nd Oncall">2nd Oncall</option>
                                                             <option value="3rd Oncall">3rd Oncall</option>
                                                         </select>
                                                     </td>
        
        
                                                 </tr>
                                             }
                                         </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                     <div class="col-12">
                                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Submit</button>
        
                                     </div>
                                 }
        
                             </form>
```

The ViewModel

```
public class EmpShifts
 {
     public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Departments>? Departments { get; set; }
     public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Employee>? Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
     public int ShiftsID { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Shifts>? Shifts { get; set; } = new List<Shifts>();
     public List<string> Dates { get; set; }

 }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Form elements must have a UNIQUE `name` attribute. See: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

Answer (score 0):

When you debug,you could press F12 to check the name attribute of your selectlist,and you'll find they all share the same name/id:

[image]

When it comes to how to fix it:

Add the property in your viewmodel:

```
public List<int> ShiftIds { get; set; }
```

modify your razorview:

```
<select class="form-select" asp-for="ShiftIds[i]" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Shifts,"Id","ShiftName"))">
            </select>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]